# How to make an absolutely positioned pseudo-element fill its scrollable parent?

Tags: html, css

I need a `position: absolute` element to fill its parent, even if the latter is scrollable.

I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/FabioSpampinato/pen/BKjjJK) for it.

As you can see the red overlay fills the div, but just as long as it doesn't get scrolled. Is there a way to fully overlay it even when scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

you need a buffer in between content and scrolling container:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.buffer {
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.buffer:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  /*pointer-events:none; if you want links and forms reachable */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="buffer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet tincidunt turpis, in pharetra mi convallis ut. Vivamus eget sodales nibh, eu placerat erat. Vivamus massa urna, volutpat non tempus eget, placerat quis elit. Nullam pretium id
    arcu sed eleifend. Phasellus sollicitudin quis ante nec ornare. Maecenas nibh eros, vehicula vel eros eget, viverra semper nisi. Nulla facilisi. Praesent pretium porttitor arcu, sit amet consequat neque luctus non. Cras sodales, justo quis tempus
    dignissim, diam est commodo orci, eget accumsan sem ante vitae sem. Curabitur quam ipsum, porta id sapien in, consectetur auctor nibh. Vivamus egestas ante vel cursus aliquet. In non ante nec velit tempus lacinia nec sollicitudin ex. Phasellus semper
    lorem a diam scelerisque, sed accumsan erat molestie. Mauris vulputate lacinia erat. Nunc urna risus, facilisis at posuere in, pulvinar quis odio. Maecenas et sollicitudin arcu. Padders Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
    aliquet tincidunt turpis, in pharetra mi convallis ut. Vivamus eget sodales nibh, eu placerat erat. Vivamus massa urna, volutpat non tempus eget, placerat quis elit. Nullam pretium id arcu sed eleifend. Phasellus sollicitudin quis ante nec ornare.
    Maecenas nibh eros, vehicula vel eros eget, viverra semper nisi. Nulla facilisi. Praesent pretium porttitor arcu, sit amet consequat neque luctus non. Cras sodales, justo quis tempus dignissim, diam est commodo orci, eget accumsan sem ante vitae sem.
    Curabitur quam ipsum, porta id sapien in, consectetur auctor nibh. Vivamus egestas ante vel cursus aliquet. In non ante nec velit tempus lacinia nec sollicitudin ex. Phasellus semper lorem a diam scelerisque, sed accumsan erat molestie. Mauris vulputate
    lacinia erat. Nunc urna risus, facilisis at posuere in, pulvinar quis odio. Maecenas et sollicitudin arcu. Padders Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet tincidunt turpis, in pharetra mi convallis ut. Vivamus eget
    sodales nibh, eu placerat erat. Vivamus massa urna, volutpat non tempus eget, placerat quis elit. Nullam pretium id arcu sed eleifend. Phasellus sollicitudin quis ante nec ornare. Maecenas nibh eros, vehicula vel eros eget, viverra semper nisi. Nulla
    facilisi. Praesent pretium porttitor arcu, sit amet consequat neque luctus non. Cras sodales, justo quis tempus dignissim, diam est commodo orci, eget accumsan sem ante vitae sem. Curabitur quam ipsum, porta id sapien in, consectetur auctor nibh.
    Vivamus egestas ante vel cursus aliquet. In non ante nec velit tempus lacinia nec sollicitudin ex. Phasellus semper lorem a diam scelerisque, sed accumsan erat molestie. Mauris vulputate lacinia erat. Nunc urna risus, facilisis at posuere in, pulvinar
    quis odio. Maecenas et sollicitudin arcu.
  </div>
</div>
```